# Will apple approve app which internally uses library developed by Google?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple

I am using `GDataXML` library developed by Google as part of their Objective-C client library. As its Google’s XML processing library and I heard that Apple don't allow to use any third party libraries in app, will they allow this one?.
(I am using this library because many iOS geeks suggest to use this one!!).

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahh ok.. I got it... Apps which uses any NON - Public i.e. Private API's get rejected, otherwise its not! And the API I am using is public.

Comment: You can use private libraries, just not private apis available in the platform.